# Across languages, what are the most common syntactic constructions that are used to form alternative questions?

Tags: syntax, linguistic-typology, questions

For those who came in late, an alternative question is one that asks the listener to identify a subset of two or more alternatives named in the question.    For example:

“Would you like the shrimp cocktail or the lemon soup?”

“Did the rhino damage the mailbox, the car, or the sliding door?”

“Would you say that the homework is easy, somewhat difficult, very difficult, or grueling?”

I’ve been searching the Net in vain for typological information about alternative questions.   Some linguistics sources that describe the different kinds of questions don’t mention alternative questions.  For example, https://serious-science.org/linguistic-theory-of-question-34

Several papers I found about linguistic research into alternative questions were, I confess, too technical for me.  Here’s one such paper:  https://compass.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/lnc3.12161

Another source only described English alternative questions:
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-alternative-questions-is-it-black-or-grey

With this in mind, I’m hoping that others on the linguistics stack exchange can answer my question.

Comment: I don't have any source for this, which is why it's a comment instead of an answer, but off the top of my head, most languages (that I know anything about the syntax of) use conjunctions for this.